# Asserting mocked calls to __iter__() method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

```
from mock import MagicMock, call
m = MagicMock()
m.foo()
for i in m:
    print m
m.bar()
print m.mock_calls
[call.foo(), call.__iter__(), call.bar()]

[call.foo(), call.__iter__(), call.bar()] == m.mock_calls
False
```

How do I assert that a mocked object was iterated over within a sequence of calls? The same thing happens if I set `__iter__.return_value` to something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working but ugly solution is `[call.foo(), ('__iter__', (), {}), call.bar()] == m.mock_calls`.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying issue is that `mock.call` returns instances of `mock._Call`, which is itself a subclass of `tuple`. Being a tuple, it inherits tuple's `__iter__` method, and you're getting that actual method instead of dynamically capturing the attribute access in order to produce chained calls as usual.

One possible workaround that's arguably better than hard-coding `('__iter__', (), {})` in your calls list is to do `call.__getattr__('__iter__')()` instead, which has roughly the same effect:

```py
>>> mock.call.__getattr__('__iter__')() == ('__iter__', (), {})
True
```

(Note that you can't do `getattr(mock.call, '__iter__')`, as that will only give you the actual `tuple.__iter__` method again)

Alternatively you can subclass `mock._Call` and build a somewhat better-behaving (well at least with respect to `__iter__`) version of `call` yourself:

```py
class _IterCall(mock._Call):

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if self._mock_name is None:
            return type(self)(name=attr, from_kall=False)
        name = '%s.%s' % (self._mock_name, attr)
        return type(self)(name=name, parent=self, from_kall=False)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.__getattr__('__iter__')()


iter_call = _IterCall(from_kall=True)
```

(It has to override `__getattr__` too, because the implementation of `mock._Call.__getattr__` will explicitly return instances of the original `mock._Call` class instead of `type(self)`)

```py
>>> iter_call.__iter__() == ('__iter__', (), {})
True
```

Both approaches have their down sides.

Answer (score 0):

If a mock object was called, its `called` attribute is `True`:

```
>>> m = MagicMock()
>>> assert m.__iter__.called, "The object was not iterated over"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.AssertionError: The object was not iterated over
>>> for i in m:
...     print(m)
... 
>>> assert m.__iter__.called, "The object was not iterated over"
>>> m.__iter__.called
True
```

In this case `m.__iter__` is a mock too, which was created "on demand" (as a result of accessing `__iter__` method).

Comment: That's a good start, but I clarified the question that there are also a dozen other calls to the mock and I'd like to assert they happen in the right sequence, with the right arguments, i.e. assert m.mock_calls == <something>

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid guessing the right syntax, so I wrote a [helper library](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/) to generate the asserts for me, based on the actual calls made.

If you add the following lines to the end of your code:

```
import mock_autogen.generator
print(mock_autogen.generator.generate_asserts(m))
```

You would get:

```
m.foo.assert_called_once_with()
m.__iter__.assert_called_once_with()
m.bar.assert_called_once_with()
```

So no more need to figure out the exact syntax by yourself, just apply the tool :)